# jQuery -> problem with combination of selectors - div -> class -> a

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with selectors in jQuery.

I have the following structure: http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/3639/structureb.png

```
<div id="myDatepicker" class="hasDatepicker" style="display: inline-block;">
    <div class="ui-datepicker-inline ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all">
        <table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="ui-body-c" onclick="DP_jQuery_1297589131703.datepicker._selectDay('#myDatepicker',1,2011, this);return false;">
                        <a class="ui-state-default ui-btn ui-btn-up-c" href="#" data-theme="c">1</a>
                    </td>
                    ...
```

In jQuery I do this:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-calendar a").live("click", function() {
    $("#myDatepicker").hide();
});
```

This works like I expect it, my datepicker will be hidden if I click on a day of the month.
But the problem is, I have two datepickers on one page. So with this jQuery code, both datepickers will "call" this function, because both matches `.ui-datepicker-calendar a`. So I need a "better" selector.

My datepickers have the names `myDatepicker1` and `myDatepicker2` (instead of the HTML code above `myDatepicker`) and I tried this:

```
$("#myDatepicker1 .ui-datepicker-calendar a").live("click", function() {
    alert("datepicker1");
});
```

But this does not work, I get no alert message. So how can I check if a user clicks a link `a` which is under the class `.ui-datepicker-calendar` (this works), and is under the id `#myDatepicker` (this does not work with my jQuery code)?

Does anyone know?

Thank you in advance & Best Regards, Tim.

Comment: Both the markup you posted and the structure you linked to show the picker's `id` to be `myDatepicker`, not `myDatepicker1`. Is that a typo? `$("#myDatepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar a")` should work as expected.

Comment: I wrote in my question: "My datepickers have the names `myDatepicker1` and `myDatepicker2` (instead of the HTML code above `myDatepicker`)..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest` to find the nearest matching data picker element:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-calendar a").live("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".hasDatepicker").hide();
});
```

Notice that `hasDatepicker` class is used which is there for each of your date pricker elements.

Comment: Hm, it does not work, the datepicker does not close. The function is called, I checked it with an alert message. This `$(".hasDatepicker").hide();` works, but closes both datepickers...

Comment: With `$(".ui-datepicker-calendar a").closest('.hasDatepicker').hide();` both datepickers will be hidden.

Comment: Also trying with `.parent().parent()... .hide()` does not work. Perhaps `$(this)` is not the clicked item, because of the `onClick`?